# Applying sliding scale price in R based on quantity

Tags: r, dplyr

R gurus,

I would like to write a function to apply dynamic prices based on quantities purchased.

Here is the dataset.

```
prices <- data.frame(from = c(0,101,201,301,401,501,601,701,801,901,1001,1101,2001), 
                     to = c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,2000,10000),
                     price = c(50,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,8,7,6,5))

purchases <- data.frame(customer = LETTERS[1:20], 
                        quantity = c(305,100,70,576,687,1200,5007,491,870,320,80,295,680,1100,1305,1024,1800,7400,3500,730),
                        bill = NA)
```

purchases dataset has quantities and price dataset has sliding scale prices for different quantity ranges.

For example, customer A purchased 305 units. To calculate billing for this quantity, first hundred units will be billed at $50, second hundred units at $45, third hundred units at $40 and remaining 5 units at $35. Mathematically:

```
purchases$bill[1] = 100*50 + 100*45 + 100*40 + 5*35
```

OR

```
purchases$bill[1] = 100*prices$price[1] + 100*prices$price[2] + 100*prices$price[3] + 5*prices$price[4]
```

I wonder what is the best way to do this using an R function to calculate bill for each purchase.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear based on the two datasets

Comment: What is the essence of `301-400` row in prices? When will it ever be use?

Comment: I have edited the question to elaborate it a bit further. In customer A example, last 5 units will be priced at 301-400 price range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R we dan do something like below:

```
c(prices$price%*%diff(replace(A<-outer(c(0,prices$to),purchases$quantity,"-"),A>0,0)))
 [1] 13675  5000  3500 21900 24240 29100 48935 19730 26700 14200  4000 13300 24100 28500 29730 27968
[17] 32700 60900 41400 24950
```

Elaboration:

```
price=prices$price
lowr=c(0,prices$to)
qnty=purchases$quantity
x=outer(lowr,qnty,"-")
M=diff(replace(x,x>0,0))
colSums(price*M)##similar to c(price%*%M)
transform(purchases,bill=colSums(price*M))

transform(purchases,bill=colSums(price*M))
   customer quantity  bill
1         A      305 13675
2         B      100  5000
3         C       70  3500
4         D      576 21900
5         E      687 24240
6         F     1200 29100
7         G     5007 48935
8         H      491 19730
9         I      870 26700
10        J      320 14200
11        K       80  4000
12        L      295 13300
13        M      680 24100
14        N     1100 28500
15        O     1305 29730
16        P     1024 27968
17        Q     1800 32700
18        R     7400 60900
19        S     3500 41400
20        T      730 24950
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a bad solution. It is not 100% accurate either.

```
library(dplyr)

prices <- data.frame(from = c(0,101,201,301,401,501,601,701,801,901,1001,1101,2001), 
                     to = c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,2000,10000),
                     price = c(50,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,8,7,6,5))

purchases <- data.frame(customer = LETTERS[1:20], 
                        quantity = c(305,100,70,576,687,1200,5007,491,870,320,80,295,680,1100,1305,1024,1800,7400,3500,800),
                        bill = NA)

prices$qty = prices$to - prices$from + 1
prices$qty[1] = prices$to[1]
prices$c_qty = cumsum(prices$qty)
prices$bill = prices$qty * prices$price
prices$c_bill = cumsum(prices$bill)
prices$id = 1:nrow(prices)

calculate_billing <- function(qty) {

  if(qty <= 100){ price_case = 1}
  if(qty >= 101  & qty <= 200)  { price_case = 2}
  if(qty >= 201  & qty <= 300)  { price_case = 3}
  if(qty >= 301  & qty <= 400)  { price_case = 4}
  if(qty >= 401  & qty <= 500)  { price_case = 5}
  if(qty >= 501  & qty <= 600)  { price_case = 6}
  if(qty >= 601  & qty <= 700)  { price_case = 7}
  if(qty >= 701  & qty <= 800)  { price_case = 8}
  if(qty >= 801  & qty <= 900)  { price_case = 9}
  if(qty >= 901  & qty <= 1000) { price_case = 10}
  if(qty >= 1001 & qty <= 1100) { price_case = 11}
  if(qty >= 1101 & qty <= 2000) { price_case = 12}
  if(qty >= 2001 & qty <= 10000){ price_case = 13}

  if(price_case==1) { 
    billing = prices$price[price_case]*qty
  }

  if(price_case>1 & price_case<=11 )  { 
    remainder <- qty%%100
    billing = prices$c_bill[price_case-1] + prices$price[price_case]*remainder 
  }

  if(price_case==12)  { 
    remainder <- qty - 1100
    billing = prices$c_bill[price_case-1] + prices$price[price_case]*remainder 
  }

  if(price_case==13)  { 
    remainder <- qty - 2000
    billing = prices$c_bill[price_case-1] + prices$price[price_case]*remainder 
  }

  return(billing)
}

purchases %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(bill = calculate_billing(quantity))
```